# MaxConnections: is it a Client or Request count?

Tags: iis

IIS allows me to set a MaxConnections value in the configuration.  What is unclear (to me anyway) is what that number means exactly, and I can't find a definitive documented answer.  Is this the maximum number of *clients* that connect simultaneously, or is the maximum number of *requests* that can be running concurrently?

For example, if I have a page that loads up some images, CSS files, scripts and content, each of those could reasonably be on a separate request socket with a modern browser.  Is each of those sockets counted against the "max", or is it counted only as 1 since they are all requests from the same client address?

Answer (score 1):

It refers to simultaneous client connects, not requests.

See here: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits

There used to be a MaxClientsMessage you could configure in IIS6 but I don't recall if it is still around or not.